# How to force Jetty to recompile JSP on each modification

Tags: jetty, jetty-9, zimbra

I want to deploy changes to Jetty and to be able to see new result on next request without having to restart Jetty with all web apps.

In official [JSP config documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP#Configuring_JSP) it is descrsibed:

> If development=true, recompilation checks occur on each request.

Here is JSP configuration from `web.xml` of my web app

```
<servlet id="jsp">
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>development</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>modificationTestInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>reload-interval</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.7</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.7</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. So what's wrong?

Linux, jetty-distribution-9.1.5.v20140505 (Zimbra 8.6.0_GA_1153)

Comment: Note: wiki.eclipse.org is for Jetty 7 and 8 (as it says on the top of the wiki page), not for Jetty 9 (which has its documentation moved, also referenced at the top of the wiki page)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Good catch! But Jetty 9 doc says the same about this http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.1.5.v20140505/configuring-jsp.html#jsp-support

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working on Zimbra, you might like to have a look at the LibreZimbra (librezimbra.github.io) project - a fork of the Zimbra OSE, created because Synacor doesn't care of even recurring 15 years old bugs.

I've stumpled across your posting, since I just have to add some extra debug code to login.jsp, in order to track down the reason for NullPointerException - and having the same problem of forcing a jsp class rebuild.

TIP: if you get mysterious 500's w/o anything in the logs, edit jetty.xml.in (needs full restart, so zmconfigd rebuilds jetty.xml), look for error handlers - enable the stacktrace output and comment out the custom error pages. Then you'll get the full exception stacktrace in the HTTP reply (browser).